# How to assign values to JS object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, error-handling

trying to assigne value to body in both cases so response sometime contains payload but when it comes as payload it adds payload as nested object as i pasted

main.js

```
const logError = (message, resp) => {
  const logErrorPayload = {
    status: resp.status,
    body : resp || resp.payload
  };
  logger().error(message,logErrorPayload);
};
```

response

```
{"level":50,"time":1565018976583,"pid":64,"hostname":"76b538d1a1fc","msg":"Error_V1 {\"status\":500,\"body\":{\"status\":500,\"payload\":{\"status\":500,\"title\":\"Internal Server Error\",\"detail\":\"Drug prices are not valid\"}}}","v":1}
```

expected

```
{"level":50,"time":1565018976583,"pid":64,"hostname":"76b538d1a1fc","msg":"Error_V1 {\"status\":500,\"body\":{\"status\":500,\"title\":\"Internal Server Error\",\"detail\":\"Drug prices are not valid\"}}}","v":1}
```

Comment: Just switch the statement, body: resp.playload || resp so in case payload is present, it is used first and if not resp is used

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for simply

```
const logError = (message, resp) => {
  const logErrorPayload = {
    status: resp.status,
    body: resp.payload,
  };
  logger().error(message, logErrorPayload);
};
```

The `resp ||` uses the whole `resp` object as the value, at least when `resp` is a truthy value (which would be expected when it has a property and therefore is an object).

Maybe you meant to use `resp && resp.payload`, which could deal with `resp` being `null`, but you'd need to do the same for accessing `.status`:

```
const logError = (message, resp) => {
  const logErrorPayload = {
    status: resp && resp.status,
    body: resp && resp.payload,
  };
  logger().error(message, logErrorPayload);
};
```

Or maybe, given that `resp` has no other properties you'd need to omit by constructing a separate `logErrorPayload`, you can just do

```
const logError = (message, resp) => {
  logger().error(message, resp);
};
```

Answer (score -2):

The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

const target = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const source = { b: 4, c: 5 };

const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);

console.log(target);
// expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }

console.log(returnedTarget);
// expected output: Object { a: 1, b: 4, c: 5 }

Comment: This sounds like a copy-paste from MDN, and has absolutely nothing to do with the question.